# reload recompiled controller src with kill and spawn command

Tags: microcontroller, gazebo, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I found that I can use kill and spawn command to restart the same controller.
That was great command to use.
But how to reload new compiled controller without restart gazebo pr2 simulator?
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9486/reload-recompiled-controller-src-with-kill-and-spawn-command/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-03-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi sam,

The pr2_controller_manager program has a `reload-libraries` command.  Running it will bring down all of the controllers, reload the libraries (and hence, the newly compiled code), and, if given the `--restore` option, it will reload your controllers.

Run:
$ rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager reload-libraries --restore

---

Originally posted by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) with karma: 649 on 2011-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) on 2011-04-04**:
The current system cannot reload only a single controller.  It must reload all of them.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-03-31**:
how to only reload one controller on recompiled src?

**Comment by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) on 2011-03-28**:
reload-libraries reloads ALL controllers.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-03-25**:
why I only reload the arm controller,but the head will move sometimes (not everytime) when I reload-libraries --restore? Thank you~